# How to connect to internet from Ubuntu which is installed in a virtual machine using VMWare Workstation?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, dhcp

Today I downloaded VMware Workstation 16 Player and I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 in a virtual machine. My host os is Windows 10 x64. The problem that I have is that I can’t find a way to connect the virtual machine to internet.

I tried following the steps posted at https://superuser.com/questions/214888/how-to-connect-to-internet-from-ubuntu-which-is-installed-in-a-virtual-machine-u but when I run `sudo ip link set ens33 up` and then `sudo dhclient ens33 -v` the terminal prompts:

> No DHCPOFFERS received.
> No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.

I restarted the computer and the virtual machine several times and nothing changes.

I would really appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thanks for your time!

Comment: In the VMware settings for the VM, confirm that your network adapter is set to “NAT” or “Bridged”. NAT will share the network IP with the host, while Bridged will ask the network DHCP server (your router) for an IP address of its own 

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matigo. I have the network adapter set to “NAT”. I tried changing to “Bridged” but when I select “Configure Adapters” and then I have to select the host network adapter, the drop-down list is empty (I can’t click it). I am still not able to connect to internet. Any other ideas of why this is happening?

Comment: If you’re not seeing a complete list of options, then you may not have the `VMNETCFG.exe` file installed. You’ll need to go to the VMware site to get it and put it in the same folder where VMware is installed. Further issues will need to be asked on a Windows or VMware-forum, though, as these issues are not specially related to Ubuntu, but instead the host software 